# tomcat is lost after adding letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, tomcat, lets-encrypt

I managed to install tomcat and letsencrypt on my VPS. The closest I was able to make it work was https://www.example.com:8443/mywar
I just wanted to make it work without needing the port and since then, everything is a mess.

www.example.com:8080 to show tomcat manager is not loading at all.

Trying to shutdown tomcat fails for: SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0]). Tomcat may not be running.

After starting tomcat, I can't really find it in the list of processes `ps -ef | grep '[t]omcat'`

And eventually, I have no idea how to make it work without the port.

here is my server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" connectionTimeout="1000000" scheme="HTTPS" sslProtocol="TLS" secure="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
        certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
        certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
    </SSLHostConfig> 
</Connector>
```

What did I do wrong?

After changing server.xml back to

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="150"
               connectionTimeout="1000000">
```

manager and war work (war works with http and 8080 port *only*)

Comment: i had not yet a chance to use tomcat but i think it will be easier to put nginx as reverseproxy infront and maybe with caching so that tomcat will have reduced ressource needings

Comment: That was chinese to me :) Is there an article I can read about it?

Comment: I saw this: https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-nginx-proxy-server-for-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/ but step 2, starting nginx fails for nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 and pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown

Comment: what did you changes?